# How can I restore master node after it failed or its instance down?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running an API service with Kubernetes. So it is set up like 3 aws instances(one master node, two worker node). I am kinda considering a scenario that when an instance that has a master node is down or crash, whatever happens, how should I restore master node?

when I use docker-swarm, it automatically backed on, then attached to worker(or worker attached to her) and it works fine!

I tried `kubeadm init` again but it shows errors

```
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml already exists
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml already exists
    [ERROR Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
```

how should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just one master you need to back up **manually** certificates and etcd before running `kubeadm init`.

I would recommend reading a really nice article [Backup and Restore a Kubernetes Master with Kubeadm](https://labs.consol.de/kubernetes/2018/05/25/kubeadm-backup.html) which tell you what files needs to be backed up and how to restore them on a new master.

They are using [Kubernetes CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to make a snapshot each 3 minutes of the `etcd`

> We will create Kubernetes [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to run that command periodically. There is no need to install `etcdctl` on the host system or to configure a cron job on the host system.

You will have to remember to backup certificates by yourself, but you only do this once and it can be done when you're cunning `kubeadm init`.

Also you can have a look into [Options for Highly Available Topology](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/ha-topology/)

Answer (score 0):

For a high availability kubernetes cluster you'll need at least three masters nodes. Please read the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rancher on top of your kubernetes cluster. When using rke, you can simply deploy a cluster within minutes and use the etcd snapshots feature.

[Backups and Disaster Recovery](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/etcd-snapshots/)

Generally talking, you should take care of the etcd node. This is were your cluster data is stored. In case of disaster, you will always restore the etcd node.